# How do I save cells in tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am making an idea/to-do pad, which uses a `UITableView` where people can add their things, then check them off. I have assigned the cells the name: 'whatsNewItems' and they are part of an `NSMutableArray`, I hope. Every time the app is closed and removed from history, the cells revert back to the original three I have embedded in code. Would I use `NSUserDefaults` and if so, how would I do so?

Comment: You need to save the data. You have many options. Please do some research.

Comment: You do not save the cells. You save the _data_. Yes, you would do this in NSUserDefaults. If you are modifying the array (model) coherently as the user changes the table, this is easy to do.

Comment: I have been researching. This is the fourth website I have looked at. I haven't found out, but no one else is willing to tell me, everyone just says 'try harder' but it's hard. If you know the NSUserDefaults way, would it be too much to ask for even a simple explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use NSUserDefaults as such:

```
- (void) saveToDo:(NSArray*)items {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:items forKey:@"user_to_do_items"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

- (NSArray*) getToDoItems
{
    NSArray* items = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"user_to_do_items"];
    return items;
}
```

Comment: App data really shouldn't be stored in `NSUserDefaults`. Use a plist or some other file or one of several other appropriate data persistence mechanisms.

Comment: @maddy - I agree, but OP asked how one would do this using NSUserDefaults so I thought I'd share.

Comment: That's fine. I am pointing it out for the OP since it is clear they lack the experience to know any better.

Comment: rmaddy. Please. I am here to learn, not get insulted by someone with higher intellect.

Comment: @Yugaman There was no insult. I was simply pointing out that due to a lack of experience that you are unaware of the fact that `NSUserDefaults` shouldn't be used. My comment was meant to be helpful, not insulting. FYI - Please precede a username with the `@` symbol. Without it, the user isn't notified of your comment. I only noticed it by accident.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to using NSUserDefaults is *not* to have *any* data "embedded in code". Instead, you should be using NSUserDefaults as the source of your data model *from the outset*. Use `registerDefaults` to get your initial data into NSUserDefaults at launch time. Then, in your table view controller, load the data from NSUserDefaults and copy it into your mutable array. That way, if the user has not made any changes (perhaps because this is the first launch of the app), your initial data is used, and if the user *has* made changes, the changed data is used. Subsequently, write the data into NSUserDefaults whenever your app is about to be backgrounded, and you're there.

Comment: And see the discussion in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch36.html#_user_defaults

Comment: With this being only my third attempt at iOS, this seems a little confusing. I shall spend some time on your answer, but the embedded results are a key component for the whole app to function (don't ask how I managed that).

Comment: App data really shouldn't be stored in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: You see, @Yugaman, you are the one asking the question. That means you don't know the answer. First you complain that no one is giving you a simple explanation; then when someone gives you a simple explanation, you push back and say "No no no". That doesn't make must sense, because, by definition, you are not in a position to judge the goodness of the answer when you see it. You need to _listen_ to what you are being told. You must adapt your approach to the way the iOS framework actually works.

Comment: The surrounding context in my book also discusses how to save in a file, in case @rmaddy is scaring you off using NSUserDefaults: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch36.html#_saving_and_reading_files

Comment: Ok, I appreciate your help matt. I will look into it tonight. Thanks for bearing with me